# Python extract words surround a word from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
id text                                                     word
1  i am working with john he is my colleague                john
2  i watched the bond movie and the bond actor was amazing  bond
3  mary is my friend and we work together                   mary
4  hello world hello python                                 peter
```

I would like to create another column where I retain the 3 words at the left and right of each word in column ["word"]. Sometimes the searched word can appear more than once, or do not have any words at the left or right, sometimes the text does not include the searched word. This is what I want:

```
id text                                                     word  retain
1  i am working with john he is my colleague                john  am working with john he is my
2  i watched the bond movie and the bond actor was amazing  bond  i watched the bond movie and the bond actor was amazing
3  mary is my friend and we work together                   mary  mary is my friend
4  hello world hello python                                 peter
```

Following this question: [Extract words surrounding a word and inserting results in a dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470373/extract-words-surrounding-a-word-and-inserting-results-in-a-dataframe-column) I tried to adapt the code:

```
retain = df.text.str.extract("(?P<before>(?:\w+\W+){,3})df['word']\W+(?P<after>(?:\w+\W+){,3})", expand=True)
```

but I only obtained two columns full of NaNs. Any suggestion?

Comment: `i` is also a word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
import re

df['retain'] = [m.group() if (m:=re.search(fr'(?:(?:\w+\W+){{,3}}){w}(?:.*{w})?\W+(?:(?:\w+\W+){{,2}}\w+)?', t)) else ''
                for t, w in zip(df['text'], df['word'])]
```

Output:

```
   id                                                     text   word                                                   retain
0   1                i am working with john he is my colleague   john                            am working with john he is my
1   2  i watched the bond movie and the bond actor was amazing   bond  i watched the bond movie and the bond actor was amazing
2   3                   mary is my friend and we work together   mary                                        mary is my friend
3   4                                 hello world hello python  peter
```